# Cauchy–Schwarz inequality for complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

How can I prove the Cauchy– Schwarz inequality for two complex numbers?
$$z_1=x_1+iy_1$$
$$z_2=x_2+iy_2$$

I can prove the triangle inequality for two complex numbers:
$$|z_1+z_2|\le |z_1|+|z_2|.$$
But I cannot prove the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality:
$$|z_1\cdot z_2|^2\le |z_2|^2|z_2|^2.$$

In my calculations, I always find the two expressions to be equal.

$a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n \in \mathbb{C}$ 
and 
$b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n \in \mathbb{C}$:
when the $n=1$
$$|\sum_{j=1}^1 a_j \overline{b_j}|^2 \leq \sum_{j=1}^1 |a_j|^2 \sum_{j=1}^1 |b_j|^2$$

Comment: use triangle inequality with on each component .

Comment: @Mr Ares, what you want to prove? Maybe you mean the Cauchy-Schwarz for two complex numbers...

Comment: Clarify your question.

Comment: Should be $\mathrm{Re}(z_1\cdot\bar{z_2})^2\le|z_1|^2|z_2|^2$.

Comment: @ziyuang Dear Sir this is inequality but the point is that, this is not really Cauchy–Schwarz inequality

Comment: @MrAres , this is CS inequality. CS inequality is about inner product, not product.

Comment: @ziyuang so what is this one!?

[proving-the-schwarz-inequality-for-complex-numbers-using-induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104694/proving-the-schwarz-inequality-for-complex-numbers-using-induction)

Comment: I think the confusion here is because the CS ineuality talks about inner products - but please note that the standard inner product on $\mathbb{C}$ is $\langle z_1,z_2 \rangle = z_1\bar{z_2}$.

Comment: @Belgi: it is not strictly clear. If one treats $\mathbb{C}$ as a one complex dimensional complex vector space, then the standard inner product is indeed as you wrote $\langle z_1,z_2\rangle = z_1\bar{z_2}$. But there's also the possibility of viewing $\mathbb{C}$ as a _two real dimensional vector space_ where the underlying field is $\mathbb{R}$. In this case the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be written as $\langle z_1,z_2\rangle_{\mathbb{R}} = \mathrm{Re}(z_1\bar{z_2})$ as ziyuang wrote. (I fixed your typo, btw.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Cauchy--Schwarz inequality is usually stated for *vectors*, not for just two numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$. In your case, if you consider numbers (i.e, the vectors of the inner product space $\mathbb C^1$), the Cauchy--Schwarz inequality is trivially true and indeed just equality:
$$
|z_1\bar{z}_2|=|z_1||z_2|.
$$

Comment: is there any difference between $|z_1\bar{z}_2|$ and $|z_1\cdot z_2|$ ?

Comment: @MrAres The values $|z_1\bar{z}_2|$ and $|z_1\cdot z_2|$ are the same. However, $z_1\cdot z_2$ is not an inner product in $\mathbb C^1$, whereas $z_1\cdot\bar{z}_2$ is.

Answer (score 2):

Every complex number $z$, can be written on the polar form:

$$ z = re^{i  \alpha}$$

Where $r$ and $\alpha$ are both real, and $r$ positive. The absolute value of this $z$ is $r$. Lets say we want to find $ |z_{1}z_{2}|$. Rewrite in polar coordinates:

$$  |z_{1}z_{2}| = |r_{1}e^{i  \alpha_{1}}r_{2}e^{i  \alpha_{2}}| = |r_{1}r_{2}e^{i ( \alpha_{1} + \alpha_{2})}|$$

And we see that our new absolute value is $r_{1}r_{2}$  since $\alpha_{2} +  \alpha_{1}$ is still real (if it was complex then this would not be true). Which happens to be the same as $|z_{1}||z_{2}|$:

$$  |z_{1}||z_{2}| = |r_{1}e^{i  \alpha_{1}}||r_{2}e^{i  \alpha_{2}}| = r_{1}r_{2}$$